# [OneSignal]. how to calling setExternalUserId and setEmail for both in the same device in ionic 4,5,6

Tags: angular, react-native, ionic-framework, frontend, onesignal

I saw someone do this in an React-Native
But it does not work in ionic

```
OneSignal.setEmail(email, null, () => {
   OneSignal.setExternalUserId(userId);
});
```

Comment: i usually call External User Id() with this function:

`this.OneSignal.setExternalUserId(userId);`

and i saw it in onesignal dashboard
 what i want to do is call   ExternalUserId() and Email  in the same devices in oneSignal
and i saw some one use this with react native:

`OneSignal.setEmail(email, null, () => {
   OneSignal.setExternalUserId(userId);
});`

i want to do the same with ionic 5

Comment: @Dev7 have you tried the same code in Ionic?

Comment: yes, but without success